# cant pop from a ListView.builder()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

i am trying to build a `ListView.builder()` widget where each item is a `ListTile`. when tap on the tile I want to execute `Navigator.of(context).pop()`.But for each item in the `ListView.builder()` has a property of `Navigator.of(context).canPop()` false so I cant pop or go back to the previous screen.

```
class AllHabitsView extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = 'all_habits_view';
  const AllHabitsView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(Navigator.of(context).canPop()); // Evaluate to true

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            print(Navigator.of(context).canPop()); // evaluate to false
            return Text('data');
          },
          itemCount: 5,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can pop when you have been pushed from another screen.

Comment: @MehranUllah right. as you can see, there are two canPop() methods. one is returning true another false.

Comment: `MaterialApp` establishes a new `Navigator`, so your `ListView` cannot see any previous screen. Why do you have `MaterialApp` here?

Comment: @PatrickO'Hara thanks. that's the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use pop without push a page to the stack of routes. I have achieved the same behavior you want. Please check the below code snippets.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyFirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyFirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          child: Text('Click me'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => MySecondScreen(key: key)));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MySecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MySecondScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
                tileColor: Colors.amber,
                onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                title: Text('List Tile $index'));
          }),
    );
  }
}
```